# Meaning of 吹っ飛ぶ

Tags: meaning

I understood 吹っ飛ぶ to mean 'blow off' as in 'the washing blew off the line' or 'he blew the door off the safe' etc.

I came across this sentence:

> そのうち学校であのポッターに出会って、二人ともどっかへ行って結婚した。そしておまえが生まれたんだ。ええ、ええ、知ってましたとも。おまえも同じだろうってね。同じように変てこりんで、同じように...まともじゃないってね。**それから妹は、自業自得で吹っ飛んじまった。** おかげでわたしたちゃ、おまえを押しつけられたってわけさ！ (Japanese TL)
> *Then she met that Potter at school and they left and got married and had you, and of course I knew you'd be just the same, just as strange, just as -- as -- abnormal -- and then, if you please,* **she went and got herself blown up** *and we got landed with you!* (original Harry Potter text. Full text added at the request of user a20)

The original text suggests something like an explosion where different pieces of the body go in different directions in an irreversible process. To me, using 吹っ飛ぶ suggests that the body just flew off somewhere but is still in one piece. Is my understanding of 吹っ飛ぶ too narrow or is this just a mistranslation? If so, what would be a better word?

Comment: Should it be “she went **and** got herself…”? I have a bigger doubt about the correctness of 自業自得 than of 吹っ飛ぶ.

Comment: @aguijonazo Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed. The Japanese sentence is as printed.

Comment: @aguijonazo Maybe my understanding of 自業自得 is incomplete, or there's a better expression you're thinking of, but the English does contain the nuance of "blown up because of something she did" or "blown up but it was her own fault" so it seems like a plausible option for the Japanese to me anyway.

Comment: Googling the phrase, I understand that it is from Japanese translation of Harry Potter (Philiosopher's stone, chapter 4)? The original text indeed uses "blown up", but I agree with you that 吹っ飛ぶ seems strange: "Then she met that Potter at school and they left and got married and
had you, and of course I knew you'd be just the same, just as strange,
just as -- as -- abnormal -- and then, if you please, she went and got
herself blown up and we got landed with you!". Of course, in the real story she didn't get blown-up though...

Comment: @Leebo - I don't know the story but 自業自得 sounds like she ended up in trouble because of her earlier action. I'm not sure the original sentence says that.

Comment: @aguijonazo The person saying this sentence despises the person who got blown up. She thinks they deserved to be blown up because of their freakish behaviour. So, at least from the English perspective, 自業自得 makes sense.

Comment: @user3856370 if it indeed is that text from Harry Potter, please add the full paragraph in English and Japanese, to ensure that the context is clear.

Comment: OK but 自業自得で吹っ飛んじまった doesn’t sound too natural to me in any case. It could be because the mood conveyed by しまった appears to contradict the mood of 自業自得 or simply because 自業自得 is being used adverbially, or both. It’s usually used in the form 〜は自業自得だ.

Comment: @aguijonazo As per a20's request I added the full text. Maybe it makes more sense now. It is unfortunate for the speaker that this person gets blown up (even though she thinks it is deserved) because she now has to look after the person's son. Do しまう and 自業自得 work together in that context?

Comment: @a20 Added as requested. I don't think the additonal text was needed for my original question but it certainly helps for the separate point we are discussing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the original English (just vanished or literally died?), but regarding the meaning of 吹っ飛ぶ, (1) the thing is intact or 'into pieces' and (2) in the same place or 'off to somewhere' are optional, i.e., 吹っ飛ぶ can be used for all those cases.

- 布団が吹っ飛んだ

A well known pun, or oyaji-gag. Maybe nobody really thinks about what exactly it means, but normally one imagines the futon is intact and flies off.

- 空気の入れすぎでタイヤが吹っ飛んだ

*I pumped too much air and the tire went flat*.　Here the tire kind of went into pieces in the same place.

---

For reference:

> [blow](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/blow/#ej-9510)
>
> **blow off**
> 1 自〈物などが〉**吹き飛ぶ**；他〈物などを〉**吹き飛ばす**；爆破する，〈人を〉銃殺する
> 2 自〈蒸気などが〉吹き出る；激怒してどなり散らす；((英略式・戯))おならをする（break wind）；他〈精力などを〉発散させる
> 3 他((米略式))…を無視［軽視］する；〈人を〉はねつける，〈人との〉約束を破る；…を欠席する，サボる
> 4 自〈あらしなどが〉おさまる，やむ
>
> **blow out**
> 1 他〈火などを〉吹き消す；自吹き消される
> 2 他〈風・爆発が〉〈窓（ガラス）などを〉**吹き飛ばす**；〈脳などを〉撃ち抜く；((俗))〈人を〉殺す；((米略式))《スポーツ》〈相手を〉たたきのめす；…を取りやめにする；自〈窓などが〉吹き飛ぶ
> 3 他((英略式))〈人を〉がっかりさせる
> 4 自〈ほお・カーテンなどが〉ふくらむ；〈支出が〉ふくらむ；〈石油などが〉噴出する
> 5 〔blow itself out〕〈あらしなどが〉吹きやむ
>
> **blow up**
> 1 自〈風船・タイヤなどが〉ふくらむ；他〈風船・タイヤなどを〉ふくらませる；〈写真などを〉引き伸ばす，〈画像を〉拡大する
> 1a 自〈事態・議論などが〉（ふくらんで）深刻化する
> 1b 他〔通例受身形で〕〈話などを〉ふくらませる，誇張する
> 2 自〈風・あらしが〉強まる，起こる
> 3 自爆発する；他〈物を〉爆発させる，爆破する
> 3a 自〈交際・関係などが〉はじける，だめになる；((略式))ひどく怒る，（人に）どなりつける≪at≫